# How I can create user with REST_API wordpress?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need create user on Wordpress. I use WP_REST_API - this is default API for WP. You can look at it "YOU_SITE/wp-json/"
I have ionic3 project and have function.

```
onSubmit(values){
    this.http.post(Config.WORDPRESS_URL + 'wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',{
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'pass'
    })
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        let token = res.json().token;
          let header : Headers = new Headers();
          header.append('Authorization','Basic ' + token);
        this.http.post(Config.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL + 'users?token=' + res.json().token,{
          username: values.username,
          name: values.displayName,
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        },header)
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            console.log(result.json());
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error.json());
          }
        )
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

But I always get error:

```
code: "rest_cannot_create_user",
message: "Sorry, but you can't create new user"
status: 401
```

admin:pass - this is admin on site and has a role admin.
Also I added to .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Please help me to find a mistake

Comment: Have you installed the Basic Authentication plugin of the documentation ? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Yes, I installed JWT Authentication for WP REST API

Comment: to use the token, try with "Bearer" instead of "basic"  `header.append('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);`

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure that login return a JWT? Try to log it. Then I noticed that you send the token via Authorization header and via query param. Try to exclude header and send only via query string and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, please look at the screen http://joxi.ru/KAg5Pejugboqam ,and I have tried both (include header and without it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue and solution. I delete param TOKEN from URL and 
create options header

```
let header = new Headers({"Authorization": "Bearer "+token});
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});
```

I have next request

```
this.http.post(Config.REGISTER, {
            username: username,
            name: displayName,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            nonce: nonce
        }, options)
```

it is work for me.